# Testing numbers using 'switch'

Tags: c

My task is:

Write a program that reads integers until 0 is entered. After input terminates, the
program should report the total number of even integers (excluding the 0)
entered, the average value of the even integers, the total number of odd integers
entered, and the average value of the odd integers.

But I had to use switch for this...

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int oddIndex = 0, evenIndex = 0, evenTotal = 0, evenSum, oddTotal = 0, oddSum;
    int userInput;
    int oddArray[oddIndex], evenArray[evenIndex];

    printf("please enter some numbers: \n");
    while (((scanf("%d", &userInput)) == 1) && (userInput != 0))
    {

        switch (userInput%2)
        {
            case 0:
                evenArray[evenIndex] = userInput;
                evenIndex++;
                evenTotal++;
                evenSum += userInput;
                break;

            default:
                oddArray[oddIndex] = userInput;
                oddIndex++;
                oddTotal++;
                oddSum += userInput;
                break;
        };
    }
    if (evenTotal > 0)
    printf("even total: %d, even average: %d\n", evenTotal, evenSum/evenTotal);
    else
        printf("there is no even numbers!\n");
    if (oddTotal > 0)
    printf("odd total: %d, odd average: %d", oddTotal, oddSum/oddTotal);
    else
        printf("there is no odd numbers!");
}
```

Is this code ok?

Comment: It's a little weird that you're using a `switch` for a 2-case scenario; an `if-else` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You *have to*? Is this an homework?

Comment: yes i know, its kind of stupid. but in the task, first he said to do this with if else, but couple of exercises latter he asked to redo this exercise using switch..@seand

Comment: yes, i have to use switch for this task. its not homework, im reading the C primer plus book @akappa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't been a C guy for years, but a few observations:

You have `int oddArray[oddIndex], evenArray[evenIndex];` declared, but the only time you use it is to add the entered number, and even that will fail because you have basically declared them as size[0], so oddArray[1] will throw an exception.

I think `[even|odd]Index and [even|odd]Total` can be combined into one variable.

I'm not sure what the standard is for C, but I really don't like the multiple declarations on one line.  There should be a single declaration per line.  Its less confusing that way.

You could also put some error handling around the input.  What happens if somebody enters "A"?  Your program would crash.  I also think your instruction should be a little more clear.  What does "please enter some numbers." really mean?

Minor thing, you forgot to indent the line after the if's at the bottom.

I would also move the reporting to a different function and reduce duplication.

Your code could turn out like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DisplayResults(char numberType[], int total, int sum);

int main(void)    
{
    int oddCount= 0;
    int evenCount= 0;
    int evenSum = 0;
    int oddSum = 0;
    int userInput;

    printf("Please enter a number followed by <enter>.  Enter \"0\" to exit: \n");

    while (((scanf("%d", &userInput)) == 1) && (userInput != 0))
    {

        switch (userInput%2)
        {
            case 0:
                evenCount++;
                evenSum += userInput;
                break;

            default:
                oddCount++;
                oddSum += userInput;
                break;
        };
    }

    DisplayResults("Even", evenCount, evenSum);
    DisplayResults("Odd", oddCount, oddSum);
    return 0;
}

void DisplayResults(char numberType[], int count, int sum)
{
    if (total > 0)
    {
        printf("%s total: %d, %s average: %d\n", numberType, count, numberType, sum/count);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("There are no %s numbers!\n", numberType);
    }
}
```

Please excuse me if I have the syntax wrong, I haven't used C in about 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

1. It does not work well on my machine (gcc version 4.4.5):

   ```
   please enter some numbers: 
   1
   2
   3
   0
   even total: 1, even average: 134519058
   odd total: 2, odd average: 67257214
   ```
2. The size of `oddArray` and `evenArray` is zero. (`oddArray[oddIndex]`, where `oddIndex` is zero) (See also: [How to initialize an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)
3. Actually, you could remove these arrays `oddIndex`, and `evenIndex`, they are only written, never read.
4. There are missing `\n`s in the last two `printf`s.
5. From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition*, p761:

   > **Use only one data declaration per line**
   >
   > [...] 
   >   It’s easier to modify declarations because each declaration is self-contained.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > It’s easier to find specific variables because you can scan a single
   >   column rather than reading each line. It’s easier to find and fix
   >   syntax errors because the line number the compiler gives you has 
   >   only one declaration on it.
6. The names `evenTotal` and `oddTotal` are confusing since you have `evenSum` and `oddSum` too. I'd call them `evenCount` and `oddCount`.

Comment: Hi, i initialized the odd/even numbers array to zero before entering the loop to 0, so it will store the first number in place0, and then I increment this index by one so the next time i will store a number it will go to the next place in the array...how should i'v done it? im reading "C primer plus" and i saw this method over there, but maybe I got it wrong..thanks! @palacsint

Comment: @user1959174: I'm not too familiar with C, but I think you should use `malloc` here. Anyway, those arrays are unnecessary here, so I would simply remove them.